# /var/log/cloud-init-output.log is not present on RHEL 7.5

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-ami, cloud-init

I've got a custom hardended RHEL 7.5 custom AMI.  I want to use user data to complete some deploy time configuration.  I've already ensured that `/var/lib/cloud/*` is removed before I create the AMI.

These are the contents of my user data:

`echo "My script fired." >> /tmp/test.txt
echo "This line should produce an output log."`

The file `/tmp/test.txt` is present, indicating the my script did indeed run. However, the expected result of the second statement is that a file `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` should be produced [in accordance with the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts).  This file is not present.

How do I make sure that user data produces the expected output log file?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It appears that Red Hat felt the file was "completely unnecessary": https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1424612

In order to view user data output, `journalctl` logs will need to be grepped:

`sudo grep cloud-init /var/log/messages`

Comment: Are these documented in RedHat.